# Virtual host setup and management for Rails apps with RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, nginx, rvm

I have a server that will be hosting several Rails apps and I'm attempting to understand how best to serve these multiple virtual hosts.  I have done this before via reverse proxy with Apache and likewise a couple of other reverse proxies such as `pound`, however I'm hoping for some clarity from a seasoned Rails developer in this area, or at least someone who's done a bit of wrenching on virtual server scenarios that have Rails apps in the mix.

I've been leaning towards using Apache 2.4 with the performance improvements even on the proxy front, however this doesn't work out too well with current backports on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  Ultimately, I'd like to have the most convenient method of configuring virtual hosts via the shell so that I can quickly go in and add new apps whilst maintaining control over the Ruby and Rails versions with RVM.

I'm open to continuing with Apache, but am likewise open to just switching over to nginx, etc.

A couple constraints that I'd like to work within: be able to run Ruby 1.9.3 (but also have the flexibility to run jruby apps) and likewise Rails 3.x and Rails 2.x apps (prefer to use .rvmrc files for each project).

**What has worked for you and could you point me towards a tutorial style aid?**